# Strange results in windows search

Tags: windows, search, display

The other week, I was doing a security audit on my exchange server and at one stage I utilized the windows search functionality.

Whilst querying some bits in the search function I run up some strange results in the display pane.

A screenshot of my findings can be found here:

[image]

What are these?

There is no way these pages would have been visited on the internet explorer instance our exchange box - are they perhaps bundled by default?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the IE FlipAhead browsing cache.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj883726(v=vs.85).aspx